# VS Code Ways to prioritize HTML emmet over Laravel Blade Snippets?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade, code-snippets, emmet

I have a QOL issue that's really irking me where if I were to press the keys (a key => tab key) or (p key => tab key) and even (li => tab) I don't get the a, p or li HTML tags that want in .blade.php files. The emmet still exists, but the blade snippets are being prioritized which is not what I want.

I've tried jamming a bunch of settings in the settings.json file:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "blade": "html",
  "blade.php": "html",
  "php": "html",
},
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "blade": "html",
  "blade.php": "html",
  "php": "html",
},
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"
```

Comment: Figured it out.. I had "editor.snippetSuggestions":"top" . I changed it to bottom and it's much better now

Comment: Hey there I had a question, I'm having a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104594/vscode-express-snippets-stop-working-after-a-while with my express snippets stopping to work. Do you think you could offer any insight? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Add `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"` in your settings.json file.